# .bat start command opening .exe but not loading info file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i am trying to start up a series of .exe's (minecraft console client) 
with only 1 click but when i setup an .bat file it opens it in the folder where the .bat is placed not where the .exe is and all the info files are where the .exe is, i would just move them but all the info files are called the same things with diffrent info and the .exe is encrypted (so nobody can take code, i think its called encrypted idk). 
How I want it to load: http://gyazo.com/a451735cb34262bf1bfc0709e7d6a11c
How it actually loads: http://gyazo.com/4ed35f560c41370d9d33f865fc67fccf
The .bat: START C:\Users\Fergal\Desktop\ConsoleClient\Vortex\Pinshi_Bwub\MinecraftClient.exe  -Would have used another gyazo but don't have enough rep :(

Comment: post the code that you are using.

Comment: Auto-connect : `MinecraftClient.exe username password server`
This will automatically connect you to the chosen server.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following batch file:

```
cd C:\Users\Fergal\Desktop\ConsoleClient\Vortex\Pinshi_Bwub
start MinecraftClient.exe
```